# How to deserialize xml with xmlns?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

Ho do you deserialze xml with a xmlns?  Below is the simplified xml containing the xmlns attribute and it fails to deserialize with the code below.  The inner exception that I keep getting is:

```
{"<nzb xmlns='http://www.nzb.com'> was not expected."}
```

Code

```
TextReader tr = new StreamReader("nzb.xml");
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings { DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore };
XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(tr, settings);                
XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
xRoot.ElementName = "nzb";
xRoot.IsNullable = true;
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Nzb), xRoot);
Nzb nzbFile = (Nzb)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
xmlReader.Close();
```

Nzb Class

```
[XmlRoot("nzb", Namespace = "urn:http://www.nzb.com")]
public class Nzb
{

}
```

nzb.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE nzb>
<nzb xmlns="http://www.nzb.com">
</nzb>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML root attribute overrides are causing the problem in XmlSerialiser. This is already defined in the XmlRoot attribute of class Nzb. So the following will work:

```
        XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(tr, settings);
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Nzb));
        Nzb nzbFile = (Nzb)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
        xmlReader.Close();
```

However, you will need to change the Nzb XMLRoot attribute's namespace to:

```
[XmlRoot("nzb", Namespace = "http://www.nzb.com")]
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. But, instead I used the XmlRootAttribute with the Namespace property and removed the nzb class attribute.