XML ignore namespace when deserialize in C#
I have a sample xml structure like:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE nzb PUBLIC "-//newzBin//DTD NZB 1.0//EN" "http://www.newzbin.com/DTD/nzb/nzb-1.0.dtd">
<nzb xmlns="http://www.newzbin.com/DTD/2003/nzb">
   <file...>
   </file>
   <file...>
   </file>
</nzb>

and .NET classes:
 [XmlRoot(ElementName = "nzb")]
 [XmlType("nzb")]
 public class Nzb
 {
     [XmlElement(ElementName = "file")]
     public FileData[] Files { get; set; } = [];
 }

 [XmlRoot(ElementName = "file")]
 public class FileData
 {
 }

and I tried:
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Nzb));
Nzb? obj = null;

using TextReader reader = new StringReader(File.ReadAllText(file));
obj = (Nzb)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

There is no way to get rid of namespace that can be different. I tried from here Error Deserializing Xml to Object - xmlns='' was not expected but still no success for my case.

Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/13705918/795683

Can this work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32106190/how-to-deserialize-xml-with-xmlns ?

Looks like a duplicate Can I make XmlSerializer ignore the namespace on deserialization? (if you are OK with using the recommended-against XmlTextReader) or How do I create a XmlTextReader that ignores Namespaces and does not check characters (if you would prefer to use more modern XmlReader).  Agree?

I resolved by:

Adding a custom XmlTextReader:

public class IgnoreNamespaceXmlTextReader(TextReader reader) : XmlTextReader(reader)
{
    public override string NamespaceURI => "";
}


Change deserialization code:

string content = File.ReadAllText(file);
// ignore everything before <nzb since I don't care about xml version or stuff
content = content.Substring(content.IndexOf("<nzb"));

using TextReader reader = new StringReader(content);
using IgnoreNamespaceXmlTextReader xmlReader = new(reader);
obj = (Nzb)serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);


I also wanted to offer a custom XmlTextReader. Using it has helped me in many cases. A simple and elegant way, but for some reason many are afraid of it.

Consider this approach:
var settings = new XmlReaderSettings { DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore };
using var reader = XmlReader.Create(file, settings);
reader.MoveToContent();

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Nzb), reader.NamespaceURI);
Nzb? obj = (Nzb?)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

We use XmlReader. Moving to the content, bypassing the DTD and so on. We get the namespace from the node and pass it to the serializer.
